# how can I get sum of for loop

Tags: python, list

my code

```
for i in range(3):
    A=(list(map(int, input().split())))
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        stk=(A[i]-(A[i-1]+1))
        print(stk)
```

result
input (1 3 4) (1 3 5) (1 2 3 4 5)

```
1 3 4
1
0
1 3 5
1
1
1 2 3 4 5
0
0
0
0
```

I want to add stk each(eg. 1/2/0)
please tell me how to add stk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sum` function to sum an iterable (you can easily convert your `for` loop into a simple generator that produces all the values of `stk`):

```
A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(sum(
    A[i]-(A[i-1]+1)
    for i in range(1,len(A))
))
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
A = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
total = 0
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    total += (A[i] - (A[i-1] + 1))
print(total)
```

(Note that when you compute a sum by storing it in a variable, you should not give it the name `sum`, because that will shadow the name of the very useful `sum` function!)

You can also do this kind of pairwise iteration with `zip`:

```
print(sum(
    b - a - 1 
    for a, b in zip(A, A[1:])
))
```

Comment: if I use sum i got error ' 'int' object is not callable'

Comment: Find the earlier line in your code where you did `sum = (some int)` and remove it.  Don’t give your variables names that are the same as builtin functions!

Comment: can you give me example like my code?
I want to understand sequentially